# Javascript - remove row after add

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with this filed and by ADD button I can add rows. To remove the rows I have put deleteRow function, but this work only if the checkbox is on the left of the form. The checkbox must be on the right form and when press the delteRow, not work

This is the script:

```
<form name="books">
  <button type="button" onClick="addRow('dataTable')">  ADD Book </button>
  <button type="button" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')">  DEL Book </button>
  <table id="dataTable" class="form">
    <tr>
      <td>Date: 
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="date_book[]">
      <td>Pages:
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="book_pages[]">
      <td>Pages total:
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="book_pages_total">
      <td width="51"><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
  </table>
</form>
```

Javascript function:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.querySelector('#' + tableID);
  var lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];

  // Create a new row by cloning the last one
  var newRow = lastRow.cloneNode(true);
  var inputs = newRow.querySelectorAll('input');

  // Clear all but first input
  [].forEach.call(inputs, (input, i) => {if (i) input.value = '';}); 

  // Add the row to the table
  lastRow.parentNode.appendChild(newRow);
}


function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {                         // limit the user from removing all the fields
                alert("You do not remove all rows");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

How to remove the rows when the checkbox is on the right form?

I hope to explain my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out elsewhere, in Roljhon's answer, the problem is the line:

```
var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
```

To correct this, you can either change the index from `row.cells[0]` to the correct index (here it would, as noted in that answer, be `6`) or you can make it more flexible, and simply select the appropriate `<input>` element from the specified `<tr>` (the `row`) variable, using the appropriate CSS selector and `Element.querySelector()`]:

```
// here we look within the <tr> represented by the 'row' variable:
var chkbox = row
  // using Element.querySelector():
  .querySelector(
    // to find the first (if any) <input> element, with
    // its 'type' attribute equal to 'checkbox' and its
    // 'name' attribute equal to the string 'chk[]'
    // (the square brackets are escaped because otherwise
    // they're recognised as part of the CSS selector):
    'input[type=checkbox][name="chk\[\]"]'
  );
```

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.querySelector('#' + tableID);
  var lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];

  // Create a new row by cloning the last one
  var newRow = lastRow.cloneNode(true);
  var inputs = newRow.querySelectorAll('input');

  // Clear all but first input
  [].forEach.call(inputs, (input, i) => {
    if (i) input.value = '';
  });

  // Add the row to the table
  lastRow.parentNode.appendChild(newRow);
}


function deleteRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox][name="chk\[\]"]');
    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
      if (rowCount <= 1) { // limit the user from removing all the fields
        alert("You do not remove all rows");
        break;
      }
      table.deleteRow(i);
      rowCount--;
      i--;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="books">
  <button type="button" onClick="addRow('dataTable')">ADD Book</button>
  <button type="button" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')">DEL Book</button>
  <table id="dataTable" class="form">
    <tr>
      <td>Date:
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date_book[]">
          <td>Pages:
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book_pages[]">
              <td>Pages total:
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book_pages_total">
                  <td width="51">
                    <input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" />
                  </td>
  </table>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L655pfj5/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).

Comment: Thanks David. Work fine!

Answer (score 1):

Your pointing to a wrong cell `cell[0]`, it points to tthe first cell not the 6th cell where your checkbox is.

Change it to :

```
var chkbox = row.cells[6].childNodes[0];
```

Comment: should be `row.cells[5]` :)